# How to combine several array arguments - SUMIF(S)? SUMPRODUCT?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I would appreciate input on this.

```
Date          Value
7-Feb-2016     100
20-Feb-2016    200 
15-Mar-2016    300
25-Mar-2016    400
```

My two criteria for a summation are

1. Date must be <= 31 Mar 2016; and if 1. is met then
2. date minus 31 Mar 2016 <= 30

In other words, for any given dates earlier than month end (here, 31 Mar 2016), what is the amount that has a day span of less than 30 days?

I would expect the output to be 700 (300+400).

I've tried this:

```
SUMIFS(sum range,date range,"<="&42460,date range,date range-42460"<=30")
```

- note that '42460' reads as 31 Mar 2016 in excel and for the second criteria I tried to use the date range minus a constant.

Is it possible to incorporate both criteria into a single line formula?

Answer (score 0):

The proper form of `SUMIFS()`:

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$5, $A$2:$A$5, ">=" & 42460-30, $A$2:$A$5, "<=" & 42460)
```

[image]

What you are looking for is everything
between 31 Mar 2016 and 31 Mar 2016 − 30 days. 
So, `31 Mar 2016 - 30 <= Date <= 31 Mar 2016`

Answer (score 0):

- Your question doesn’t (entirely) make sense.  You have the conditions

  1. Date must be ≤ 31 Mar 2016, and
  2. Date minus 31 Mar 2016 ≤ 30

  Well, if date ≤ 31 Mar 2016,
  then date minus 31 Mar 2016 automatically must be ≤ ***zero***. 
  I.e., your second condition is automatically true
  for every date (row) that satisfies the first one.

  From your example
  (dates in March are included, dates in February are excluded),
  I assume that you mean 31 Mar 2016 minus date ≤ 30. 
  This is more practically expressed as date ≥ 31 Mar 2016 minus 30
  (i.e., date ≥ 1 Mar 2016). 
  Incidentally, I notice that Scott Craner (no relation)
  fixed this for you without explaining it.
- Don’t convert dates to numbers and then use those numbers in formulas. 
  That leads to a spreadsheet that you will have trouble maintaining
  and nobody else will be able to understand.  You should either

  - Put the end date in a cell (say, `E1`) and then do

    ```
    =SUMIFS($B$2:$B$5, $A$2:$A$5, ">=" & $E$1-30, $A$2:$A$5, "<=" & $E$1)
    ```

    or
  - Put the date into the formula in a way that can be understood
    by both humans and Excel:

    ```
    =SUMIFS($B$2:$B$5, $A$2:$A$5, ">=" & DATE(2016,3,31)-30, $A$2:$A$5, "<=" & DATE(2016,3,31))
    ```
  - You could also do

    ```
    =SUMIFS($B$2:$B$5, $A$2:$A$5, ">=3/1/2016", $A$2:$A$5, "<=3/31/2016")
    ```

    if you know the begin and end dates,
    but I can’t figure out how to do the math (subtract 30 days)
    in a single line formula using this notation.
- You realize, of course, that if `E1` is 28 February 2015,
  then `E1-30` is 29 January 2015, right? 
  If you really want a 30-day window, that’s fine with me. 
  But, if you really want to add all the entries for a given month, say so,
  because there are better ways of doing that.